# Applescript: pdf to pptx conversion

Tags: applescript, adobe, acrobat

I'm trying to convert pdf to pptx invoking adobe acrobat using AppleScript.
Below code executes fine without any error but there isn't any output created.

```
--somecode--
save active doc to filePath using conversion "com.adobe.acrobat.pptx"
```

conversion using text class works fine.

```
save active doc to filePath using conversion "com.adobe.acrobat.plain-text"
```

I found this on adobe forum, and it remained unresolved(pdf to html).
https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-sdk/pdf-to-html-conversion-with-interapplication-communication-api-in-mac-os/td-p/9294002

Just to add I'm using adobe acrobat pro dc trial version.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the trial version you're using doesn't disable saving files to pptx? Trial software often has limitations built in.

Comment: I'm not sure of that, I haven't been able to find a definite yes or no. Using the trial version I'm able to convert the pdf to pptx manually using the GUI options.

Comment: Well, if you can do it in the GUI, you can ostensibly do it by AppleScript. The only other thing I can think is that maybe you have the uniform type identifier wrong. When I check the few pptx files I have, their UTI is listed as "org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation".

Comment: I verified the conversion class by invoking get conversions. It returned list of classes available to used for various conversion formats.

Comment: I'll have to download the pro trial version and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work. Used AppleScript to invoke adobe javascript.
Going through posts in various forums, found a user following the same approach for rtf documents.

```
set myScript to "this.saveAs(\""& output_file_path && "\", \"com.adobe.acrobat.pptx\");"
do script myScript
```

instead of

```
save active doc to filePath using conversion "com.adobe.acrobat.pptx"
```